# Skip AIR update

Tags: air, skip

Imagine I have an AIR application to update: the preceding version number is 0.0.1, the current one is 0.0.2. Now, the preceding app is installed on many different pcs. I want to update ONLY some clients, based on a particular ID. Is it possible to skip update process for some clients?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, it is possible.  You can do just about whatever you need if you write your own code to check for updates, download updates to a local file, then call [System:Updater.update()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/) or [Air.update:ApplicationUpdater.installFromAIRFile()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/)  The old [AIRUpdater.js](http://code.google.com/p/facedesk/source/browse/trunk/js/AIRUpdater.js?spec=svn11&r=11) example from AIR 1.0 can get your started.

The problem is you'll have to update all of your 0.0.1 clients with new code before they can make a decision on 0.0.2.  And if you don't have a good way to ensure they've all been updated before deploying your next version, you'll probably want to change the location of the update descriptor file in your intermediate version.  Otherwise you may end up with straggler 0.0.1's that skip the intermediate version and update to 0.0.2 without your ID checking.

And I haven't tried this yet, but it  might be even easier to use the newer Air.update:ApplicationUpdater class from AIR 1.5 and put your ID checking in the updateStatus event.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. The fact is I want to use the update mechanism to load everyday new contents (swf) when a particular client needs them. So, I imagine there would not need to worry about jumping from 0.0.1 to 0.0.4 if this last one has contents for myID client.